# Basic PIC Programming issues

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I am writing PIC code in C and encountered the following problems:

- When I write my delay as `_delay_ms(500)`, my code doesn't compile, it says it didn't recognize this instruction. I am using MPLAB.
- I want to write a program that would count how many time the push button is pressed then return that value and display it using LED's. I know how to display it, but not how to make the program to wait for the push of the push button on the pickit.

```c
    main()
    {
        TRISA=0;//Sets all ports on A to be outputs
        TRISB=1;//Sets all ports on B to be inputs

        for(;;){
            if(PORTBbits.RB0==1){//When the button is  pressed the LED is off
                PORTAbits.RA1 =0;
                count=count+1;
            }
            else{
                PORTAbits.RA1=1;
                count = count +1;
            }
            if (count > 20){//if count =20 aka 20 button presses the LED turns on
                PORTAbits.RA0=1;
            }
            else{
                PORTAbits.RA0=0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: From a 20sec google session, it appears that you've used the AVR library function `_delay_ms`, when you should be using the PIC library function `delay_ms`

Comment: I tried Delay_ms(1000) still gave me the same error is there a library that i should include?

Comment: See here: http://www.microchip.com/forums/m598683.aspx (Don't forget Microschip has its own forum dedicated to all things PIC) - No idea on the library, I use AVRs - not PICs.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues:

- Assuming you're using a PIC24 or a dsPIC, you need to include libpic30.h
- Before you include libpic30.h you need to #define FCY to be your instruction rate so that the delay takes the correct number of cycles. See the comments in the libpic30.h file for details.
- The function is `__delay_ms` not `_delay_ms`. Note that there are two underscores at the beginning.
- The name is all lower case, not `Delay_ms` as in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add delay in your code when you detect a key is pressed. As you are saying the _delay_ms(500) is not recognized, You can try something like following:

```
 unsigned char x;

        // Just waste a few cycles to create delay
        for (x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            // No operation instruction
            Nop();
        }
```

You can create your own delay function with specific number of iterations of this for loop. Measure the exact delay created by this function using a profiler if you need. IMO any arbitrary delay, like say 100 iterations as stated above shall work.